# Background AsyncTask Takes to long to fullfill

Tags: android, linq, xamarin, android-asynctask

I'm developing an Android App (Android 6.0 and above) and I have performance issues with large XML-Files. (about 17 mB)

When the app is started the required XML-document is loaded **from the private storage** and a List is returned (takes about 2-3 sek.) and filled in an custom adapter -> this works perfectly fine.

But the user can start a synchronization manually inside the app (e.g.: data 
was updated on server)

Therefor I've implemented a background download-service so that the UI stays responsive during the download.
The downloaded data is stored inside the private folder again.

**problem:**

The background download works perfectly and my UI stays responive until I start reading the information from the new XML-File.

I don't get any result back -> even after 3 min there is no return value from the function although I use the same function for reading the XML like I do at the beginning -> GetKontaktliste()

```
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
alert.SetPositiveButton("Synchronisieren", async (senderAlert, args) =>
                    { new DownloadTask(this).Execute("");}); 
}


public class DownloadTask : AsyncTask
    {
        protected override Java.Lang.Object DoInBackground(params Java.Lang.Object[] @params)
        {

            App_Tools lAppTools = new App_Tools();

            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(async state =>
            {
                //Download Function -> received XML-Data is saved in local storage
               bool lKontakte = await lAppTools.DownloadKontakte(_context);
               bool lVorgaenge = await lAppTools.DownloadVorgaenge(_context);
               bool lVorgaengeImport = await lAppTools.ImportVorgaenge(_context);

                if (lKontakte == true)
                {

                    //Problem is that i dont get any results back here 

                    List<KontaktItem> lResult = new List<KontaktItem>();
                    LinqAbfragen lLinq = new LinqAbfragen();
                    lLinq.GetKontaktliste();
                }
            });
           return true;
        }
}




 public class LinqAbfragen
    {
             //Read Contacts
            public List<KontaktItem> GetKontaktliste()
            {
                List<KontaktItem> lResult = new List<KontaktItem>();

                //Read from IEnumerable<XElement>
                var KontakteAsXElement = ReadXmlAsXElement("Kontakte.xml", "Kontakt");

                lResult = (from kontakt in KontakteAsXElement
                           select new KontaktItem
                           {
                               AdressNr = kontakt.Element("AdressNr").Value,
                               Vorname = kontakt.Element("Vorname1").Value,
                               Nachname = kontakt.Element("Name1").Value,
                               xmlData = (string)kontakt.ToString()
                           }
            ).ToList();
                return lResult;
            }
    }
```

Comment: Do not use an AsyncTask for this.  AsyncTask is for short, quick methods.  All AsyncTasks in the app are run on the same thread, so if one of them takes too long they deadlock your system.  Use a Thread for anything that will take more than a few hundred ms worst case.  This includes anything with a network call.

Comment: I've tried to read the downloaded contacts inside a new thread, but nothing happens.
The function for reading the XML-File does not return any result :S

Comment: Are you sure the XML-file has downed successfully and saved correctly in local storage?

Comment: Sry for my late response.
Yeah it was all finished. I've had problems with the memory :S